# vba - Call a function in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, function, loops

I need to call an homemade function (GetCoordinates) in a loop and apply it at each loop step.

I have a column with data (Starting at L2) and I need to apply my personnal function GetCoordinates to this data and write the result on the column next to it (so starting at M2)

```
NumRows = Range("L2", Range("L2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("L2").Select
      For x = 1 To NumRows
         Selection.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=GetCoordinates(L&x)"
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
```

My problem is that I don't know how to apply my function to each cell. How should it be written so that the function is called for each cell in the loop? (The GetCoordinates function works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting in all the formulas without a loop. To write te formulas in column M and use column L as the formulas argument then use,

```
 Range(cells(2, "M"), cells(rows.count, "L").End(xlup).offset(0, 1)).Formula = _
     "=GetCoordinates(L2)"
```

Your own might have been closer with,

```
Selection.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=GetCoordinates(L" & x & ")"
```

But you were mismatching Do ... While and For ... Next loops.

Comment: What column is the input data and what column do you want the formula in?

Comment: The input is the L column and the result should be in the M column (both on the same line)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 NumRows = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For x = 2 To NumRows
     Cells(x, "M").Value = GetCoordinates(Cells(x, "L"))
  Next
```

Comment: Thank you it worked as well. Yet I don't know which one of the 2 solutions is the fastest (i have about 6000 lines to process)

Comment: Add a timer at start of code `Debug.Print "Start Time: " & Time` and at the end `Debug.Print "Start Time: " & Time` , you will come to know. :-)